# How to receive big OSC blob in Java

Tags: java, blob, osc, oscp5, javaosc

I am trying to receive quite big OSC blob (array of more than 10000 bytes) from PureData with Java.

I tried [oscP5 library](https://code.google.com/p/oscp5/) and I got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` above around 1500 bytes.

I have the same with [JavaOSC library](https://wush.net/trac/lsu-idt/wiki/JavaOSC) with the same limitation (with code example from https://wush.net/trac/lsu-idt/wiki/JavaOSC).

`NetUtil` [3] lib give me `de.sciss.net.OSCException: Error while receiving OSC packet: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException`

However I can easily receive those blob and even bigger one with PureData.
So I guess something is wrong with my Java configuration.

I tried to increase the VM memory with -Xms512m and even -Xms2048m, but this doesn't help.

Comment: Just see if you are reading the data twice.

Comment: if you mean reading OSC data twice, maybe but then why is it working with smaller blobs with the same code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oscP5 library has a default datagram size of 1536, which is why you experienced that bound.  You can change the datagram size with OSCProperties::setDatagramSize(), which is used in the constructor of the OscP5 object:

OscP5(Object theParent, OscProperties theProperties)

See this link for an old example from the Processing forum:

https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/query-re-sending-large-number-of-values-to-processing-via-osc-from-supercollider.html

Clay Budin
NYC